# How to prove the adjoint of this operator is the $-T-I$

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators

Suppose $\mathbb R$ is a finite-dimensional real inner product space, and $T$ is an operator on it with the following properties

$1. T^2=T^*$

$2. T$ is invertible

$3. T-I$ is invertible

Prove that $T^*=-T-I$

I don't know how to approach this problem. In particular, I don't know how to use $T$ and $T-I$ are invertible these two properties. Thus, any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: One point to consider: what does $T^2 = T^*$ tell you about the eigenvalues of $T$?

Comment: @Ben Grossmann To be honest, I can tell nothing about the eigenvalue of $T$ from $T^2=T^*$. I can only know that $T$ shouldn't have eigenvalue 0,1 by the invertibility of $T$ and $T-I$...

Comment: You could get information using the fact that $T^*$ has the same eigenvalues as $T$. In any case, the approach that I suggest in my answer doesn't require this kind of analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note  that
$$
T^2 = T^* \implies (T^2)^* = T^{**}\implies (T^*)^2 = T \implies (T^2)^2 = T.
$$
Use the invertibility of $T$ and $T-I$ to rewrite the above equation as $T^2 = -T-I$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get why $(T^*)^2$ is equal to $T$ could you please explain this further? Thanks

Comment: Also, after a quite long time of thinking about this problem, now I feel like I'm not really able to manage it...Could you please post the answer? Thank you very much!

Comment: Regarding your first comment, I've added a clarifying intermediate step to my hint; hopefully it's clear now. To your second comment; I'll post a complete answer if you haven't figured it out 9 hours from now (when I'll have woken up and started the day). In the meantime, a further hint: we can write the last equation as $p(T) = 0$, where $p(x) = x^4 - x$. What does the factorization of this polynomial tell you?

Comment: I slightly know what you mean. Since for all $u,v\in V$ $\langle Tu,v\rangle=\langle u,T^*v\rangle=\langle u,T^2v\rangle=\langle (T^*)^2u,v\rangle=\langle T^4u,v\rangle$ Thus $T^4=T\implies T(T^3-I)=0$ since T is invertible $T^3-I=0$ Thus $(T-I)(T^2+T+I)=0 $. Again, since $T-I$ is invertible, we can only have $T^2+T+I=0$. Then $T^*=-T-I$ Is this right?

Comment: I use the inner product to show that $T^4=T$, I forget that $T^*=T^2\implies (T^*)^*=(T^2)^*\implies T=T^4$ we can give adjoint to both side

Comment: Yes, the second approach is what I had in mind. In any case, that’s all correct, well done.